# Responding to an input when executing a python script through SSH

Tags: python, ssh

I am currently using a windows machine and trying to SSH to an Ubuntu Server, using PKI. I need to run the python script test.py using the sudo command. The script contains an input that will ask me for a number after running test.py. I have tried putting for a number after the sudo command but it did not work.

```
import subprocess

command = "ssh -t john@x.x.x.x echo 'john' | sudo -S python3.7 ./Desktop/test.py"

command = command.split()

out = subprocess.check_output(["scp", "test.py", "john@x.x.x.x:./Desktop"])

run_script = subprocess.run(command, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
```

Example of test.py:

```
import subprocess

choice = input("Choose a number: ")

if choice == 1:
    result = subprocess.run(['cat' '/etc/passwd'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
    print(result.stdout.decode('utf-8'))
```

How can I respond to this input and where should I put it in my code?

Answer (score 0):

If your remote command's standard input is connected to your Python script, simply use that.

```py
run_script = subprocess.run(command,
    stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE,
    input="1\n", text=True)
```

I'm guessing you'll want to capture the output with `capture=True`, and probably also add `check=True` to the keyword arguments as well.

The addition of `text=True` saves you from having to `encnde` your input into `bytes`, and similarly from having to `decode` the output.

Comment: I got the error builtins.TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' after adding input="1"

Comment: Yeah, like I explained, you need either `text=True` or `input=b"1\n"`. I'll update the answer. Sorry for the messy formatting (I'm on mobile).

Comment: See updated answer now. If your Python is older than 3.7, try the poorly-named and now obsolescent synonym `universal_newlines=True`

Comment: My python version is 3.7 but now im facing another error called EOFError: EOF when reading a line. When I place stdin=subprocess.PIPE it also said that stdin and input arguments may not both be used.

Comment: Oh sorry, one PIPE too many. Unfortunately, I'm not in a place where I can test this.

Comment: Its okay im still trying it